# Save CSS Related To Dreamweaver Document

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I find this incredibly annoying with Dreamweaver, everytime I go to save my document I have to tab into each css file and save them individually. Not a problem with one css file, but when you have 3 or 4 it is a pain in the ass. Is there anyway to save your dreamweaver document and all related css files in one hot key?

Comment: I use DW daily but I've never seen that as a problem. I always ctrl-s after I've edited something. Also if you use the built in publishing that asks to save files before uploading to your site. I recommend saving your files all the time while editing. At least on my pc DW has been known to crash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's isn't a way to save *related* files as a group, but there is "Save All" in the file menu, and a "Save All" icon in the toolbar (two floppy disks).

Comment: Yeh i saw that, I'll have to set a hotkey for it I suppose. Can't believe adobe/macromedia haven't implemented this.